# Tensorflow models im2txt issue

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

My plantform is MAC OS 10.12, when I using im2txt to test

```
with tf.gfile.FastGFile(captions_file, "r") as f:
caption_data = json.load(f)
```

there has an error

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

then I have try to change type to string , encode to 'utf-8' and object to string…… but there is no effect

Comment: `json.load(f.read())` ?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
 with tf.gfile.FastGFile(captions_file, "r") as f:
        caption_data = json.loads(str(f.read(), encoding = "utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 1):

try modify code like this:

```
with open(captions_file, "r") as f:
    caption_data = json.load(f)
```